# How to connect a project from IDEA to Gitlab

Tags: intellij-idea, gitlab

Is it possible to connect a project from IDEA to Gitlab?
There are no problems with GitHub, you specify a github account, then VCS-> Import into and it creates a project in your account. But with GitLab I don't see such a possibility. Maybe there is some way?
Or just manually throw it in there?

Answer (score 5):

If all you want to do is create a project, that is as simple as pushing the repo. In GitLab, you don't have to create the project in the UI first. You can simply push directly to a project namespace that does not yet exist. The project will be created when you push to it.

Therefore, all you have to do is configure your git remote per usual, then push.

```sh
git init
git checkout -b main
echo "# My Project" > README.md
git add README.md
git commit -m "initial commit"
git push --set-upstream git@gitlab.com:namespace/myproject.git main
```

Then you'll see the message from the remote in the git console log

```
remote: The private project namespace/myproject was created.
```

In the JetBrains IDEs, you can simply configure the remote and push.

You only have define the remote ahead of time in the terminal. For example:

```
git remote add origin git@gitlab.com:namespace/project
```

Then in the IDE, when you go to push, you'll see the ability to push to the new remote/branch.

[image: push dialog]

Then you'll also note in the `git` tab console you'll see the message from the remote that the project has been created.

[image: New repo log]

Comment: thank you for such broad steps-by-step guide. If you don't mind, I'd like to point at something:
>You only have define the remote ahead of time in the terminal. For example:

There is no need to define the remote in the terminal, it will be possible to do in Push dialog - you will have 'Define remote' instead of 'origin:master' if you don't have remote defined.

Comment: Yeah, the push dialog _does_ let you define a remote if one has not been configured; you click on the text that says "Define remote" and it will pop up the dialog to enter the remote. However, it attempts to validate the setting against the server, so it won't work for a remote that does not yet exist on the server. That may be a setting that can be changed @RuslanKuleshov -- at least that's what I see in JetBrains 2021 apps

Answer (score 4):

Full integration for GitLab hasn't been implemented yet, but there is a feature request for that:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-109294

Meanwhile, you can create a repository in GitLab, then press Cmd/Ctrl+K and Click "Commit and push". In Push dialog there will be "Define remote" button - click on it and paste URL to GitLab's repository.

If it's HTTPS then you'll be prompted with username and password - enter them, alternatively you can enter Username and Personal access token (in password field)