# Convert IntelliJ IDEA project into GitLab project, if I didn't do it upon project creation

Tags: git, intellij-idea, gitlab

If I do *not* create an IntelliJ IDEA project via "New | [Project from Version Control...](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/clone-gitlab-project.html)", the [GitLab plugin](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/gitlab.html) doesn't work, and even the "GitLab" submenu is missing under "Git". Even if all the other Git IDEA functionality works.

Is it possible to fix it additionally, without having to re-create the project?

"Version Control | GitLab":
[image]

"Git | [Manage Remotes...](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/set-up-a-git-repository.html#add-remote)":
[image]

"Version Control | Git":
[image]

- but still there is some magic settings missing, which distinguish between how the project has been created. What is this missing part?

I cannot find any visible difference between the settings of a project imported from `pom.xml` and project created via "New | Project from Version Control...", apart from the difference that in the former the GitLab functionality does not work, whilst in the latter it does :)

[How to connect a project from IDEA to Gitlab](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69970637/2886891) is not an answer, even if the title sounds similar.

Comment: Can you share your inteliji Settings ?  Settings>Plugins > Git   and Settings>Version Control >Git  . also can you check this file : git config --global --edit

Comment: @Mohamedaminebenhassen See my edit. Global git settings should not matter, because 1. the other Git functionality is OK, 2. when I create the project via "New | Project from Version Control..." using the very same gitlab URI as when cloning the repo from command line, the GitLab functionality is OK.

Answer (score 0):

For the GitLab icon to appear:

1. You must be logged in via your Gitlab account via Settings | Version Control | GitLab
2. You must clone Gitlab project from that account (and the url of the remote must match the url in the account settings)

Comment: I know that and I wrote that it works like this! My question is what can I do if I did **not** create the project as clone GiLab, but called `git clone URL` from command line and then created the project from the `pom.xml`. If I can additionally, **later**, bring the GitLab magic to the project.

Comment: The icon should be visible then if you are logged to your Gitlab account in IDE settings.

Comment: If I have another GitLab project open in another Idea window, and this one **is** working, I'd expect that I am indeed logged to my GitLab account. How do you suggest to verify it?

Comment: It should work indeed. To verify it check Gitlab account via Settings | Version Control | GitLab is your account logged in.